# Declaring vector variable in Unity, System.Windows and "Vector" type not working

Tags: c#, vector

I'm using Visual Studio Code on a Mac (not Visual Studio for Mac) and using C#.

I've been trying to figure out how to declare a vector variable and learnt it's because I'm looking for commands within the `System.Windows` namespace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.vector?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) though correct me if I'm wrong. I added this to the references at the beginning (see line 4).

But it's still showing up greyed-out as though the namespace isn't being used, and the vector declaration is still an error.

[image: Image below]

Any help is appreciated! Is this because I'm on a Mac (M1 chip with most recent OS update, Sonoma)? Or is there another simpler way to go about this? Thanks!

Edit: Even after removing System.Numerics and specifying the variable as 'new' as said in a comment I get the error code **CS0246** over the first the 2 words "Vector".

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Windows;

public class TestingVectors : MonoBehaviour
{    
    Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share your code as formatted text

Comment: [`Vector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0) exists in the `System.Numerics` namespace too, which you have also included. Remove the reference you don't need or be specific when defining `new System.Windows.Vector(20, 30);`.

Comment: What is the exact error message provided?

Comment: I've specified the error message I get (CS0246) and updated the code as formatted text to match another file I've created solely for testing this. Sorry for the delay, I'm Australian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that normal Vector-type variables ARE under the namespace System.Windows but are unrelated to Unity Vector variables and incompatible.

By removing `using System.Windows` and ensuring `using UnityEngine` remains at the top, and by using the variable type `Vector3` (3D space) or `Vector2` (2D space) everything works. I shouldn't have overlooked the fact I'm using Unity to code!

**Example**:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class YourClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Declare a Vector3 variable
        Vector3 myVector = new Vector3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    }
}
```